# Raspian kernel cross compilation failing

Tags: compilation, linux-kernel, arm, raspbian, toolchain

I want to cross-compile a Raspbian kernel that I downloaded from *[www.github.com/raspberrypi/linux](http://www.github.com/raspberrypi/linux)* on my host machine (Linux Mint Cinnamon 64bit).
I was executing the following steps:

1. Create folders leading to path home/sven/Develop/Raspbian
2. Cloning repo from link above leading to home/sven/Develop/Raspbian/linux containing the source code
3. Cleaning kernel by running **make mrproper**
4. Creating .config from my running raspberry pi 3B+ by running **sudo scp pi@.../proc/config.gz .** and then unzipping it with **gunzip -c config.gz > .config**
5. Running **ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=${CCPREFIX} make oldconfig**
6. **grep -v DEBUG_INFO < .config > newconfig**
7. **mv newconfig .config**
8. **ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=${CCPREFIX} make oldconfig**
9. **ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=${CCPREFIX} make**

However, the last step is always failing (Error 2 or Error 1). I have also tried the following commands that have also been unsuccessful:

- make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=${CCPREFIX}
- make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=

If I type in only make oldconfig or only make, it works but then I have no idea if it's really compiled for ARM or with the gcc compiler...

---

My .profile file looks like this at the end:

PATH=/opt/toolchain/.../gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/:$PATH
export CCPREFIX=arm-linux-gnueabihf-

I have already tried the PATH without the "/bin/" at the end, also not working.

Does anyone have an idea???

Comment: What are the errors you are getting at the last step? Also, if you run just `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc --version` from the command line, do you see your (cross) gcc version or are you getting an error?

Comment: If I run `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc --version`, I get the following:
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc., therefore, it seems to work properly

Comment: I just tried it again, without changing anything and it worked. Maybe all it took was a VM reboot. I will come back if new problems appear but it seems to be working well for the moment